# Alternate to ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, pentaho

I have a piece of javascript which checks whether a specified tab is present in the tab or not. When I plugin this code in my open source etl tool "pentaho", its not identifying ActiveXObject. This is because my etl tool is using mozilla javascript version. Is there a way to do this by having any alternates to ActiveXObject? Thank you.

```
  main();
    function main(){
    var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    ExcelApp.Visible = false;
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = false
    var filenamer="D:\\wo_etl\\Input Files.xlsx"
    var ExcelBook=ExcelApp.Workbooks.open(filenamer, false, false);
    ExcelBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Active
    ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = true
    ExcelApp.Quit();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no.

ActiveXObject is a Internet Explorer-specific object. Using it will limit your page to that particular browser

Comment: Is it? how does Mozilla browser work with excel files? Thank you.

Comment: As far as i know, it doesn't work with excel files, except being able to download them. Being able to work with excel files like your example is a proprietary extension of Internet Explorer. If you absolutely need to work with excel files, you might want to look at Java applets, which you may get to read excel files through a library, or you could upload the file to a server which then performs the check.

Comment: Even if Firefox could use ActiveX components, that wouldn't be very useful for this use case, because Firefox uses the TraceMonkey/JaegerMonkey/IonMonkey family of javascript engines, whereas Kettle is a Java application, so it uses Mozilla's Rhino engine (which is a pure java implementation).